# Evaluating $\sin^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate
>   $$\sin^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\cot^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}}+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}}+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}}+\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right]$$

$$\sin^{-1}\left[\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)+\dfrac{5\pi}{12}\right]$$

But domain of $\sin^{-1}$ is $[-1,1]$ and $\left(2+\sqrt{3}+\dfrac{5\pi}{12}\right)$ seems out of the domain.

But actual answer is $0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please share and cross check the source as $$\sin^{-1}$$ having  some form of $\pi$ does not look likely

Comment: I have double checked the source but same problem, I think may be printing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some errors in your expression. If you notice $5\pi /12>1$

Also $$\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{\pi}{12}$$

So I don't think your expression is correct. But if you put the expression $$\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}$$ inside the $cot$ then it's $0$

So I suppose the correct expression would be
$$\sin^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}+\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)+\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2}\right)\right]$$